# How to create common function in laravel for get query value to header and footer

Tags: laravel

I fetch a problem that i want to get query value from database in header or footer. Have any guys can me help how can i get (setting or user) table value in header or footer template.

please see my AppServiceProvider

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use DB;
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
       $employeedata = DB::table('employees')->get();
       return view('partials.sidebar');
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {

    }
```

Comment: I do not quite understand your question, please watch your grammar and add more detail.

Comment: I mean i want to get value from database for header or footer

Comment: where can i create common function?

Comment: If what you are trying to say is "get a value from the database and show it in the header/footer" then I'd use a ViewComposer loaded globally, so that you are able to show the fetched value everywhere you want.

Comment: Will your footer, header be common for across all the pages ?

Comment: Yes @vikash i want same that

Comment: You can define two blade file header & footer. share the query value across both the view using AppserviceProvider. include the view in one base blade file and extend that blade file in all of your application

Comment: @vikash where can i create query please.

Comment: And how can i get value for header| footer

Comment: @JewelFarazi see my answer. you can solve using my answer

Comment: @JewelFarazi did it help you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your modified question

Change your service provider boot method like below

```
public function boot()
{
   $employeedata = DB::table('employees')->get();

    View::composer('partials.sidebar', function($view) use($employeedata) {
    $view->with('employeedata',$employeedata);
    });
}
```

Then your sidebar.blade.php you can access employee date like this

```
{{ $employeedata }}
```

Comment: please see i get tihs ErrorException in AppServiceProvider.php line 20: Undefined variable: employeedata (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\loginmanagement_log3\resources\views\layouts\template.blade.php) (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\loginmanagement_log3\resources\views\layouts\template.blade.php)

Comment: you are passing data to sidebar.blade php then how you are excepting to get at template.blade.php . if you want to pass to template the creat one another view composer like above for template view also

Comment: I got the issue, you can check my updated answer within the closure you have to use `use`. please try my updated answer.

Comment: yes but i include in template.blade.php sidebar please see @include('partials.sidebar').

Comment: thaks a lot for your help.

Comment: Glad to help @JewelFarazi. I also didn't used view composer. I read laravel documentation of view composer and answered your question. Thank you also for giving me the opportunity to learn :).

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using view composer.

**Step 1**

Create two files **header.blade.php** & **footer.blade.php** file inside the **view** directory of your project

**Step 2**

Go to the AppServiceProvider.php file's `boot()` method of your application.

```
$query 1 = ""; // write your query here

view()->composer('header', function($view) use ($query){
        $view->with('query',$query);
    });

view()->composer('footer', function($view) use ($query){
        $view->with('query',$query);
    });
```

Now in your header.blade.php & footer.blade.php file use `{{ $query }}` that will let you access you query object.

You can pass variable normally by any method like you pass in view from controller generally